# Scroll by pushing side of screen with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Windows 8 has this neat feature where you scroll through your apps by "pushing" the side of the screen.

I want to know if anyone has any ideas to accomplish this in JavaScript.

Essentially, the screen does should NOT scroll if you hover over the side of the screen, but should rather be able to detect when the user is attempting to go beyond the viewport and cannot.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using something along the lines of:

```
    $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
        if (getIsPageEdge()) {
            if (lastX == e.pageX) {
                console.debug('pushing the page');
            }
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            if (lastUpdate == null || now - lastUpdate > 500) {
                lastUpdate = now;
                lastX = e.pageX;
            }
        }
    });
```

Essentially, onmousemove, if the cursor is at the edge of the viewport, and the X value is not changing (with a time delay added to compensate for the event processing delay), then change the scroll position of the containing div.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just need to figure out their algorithm if you want to duplicate it.

You can track the last several known locations of the pointer to determine velocity and direction and stop the scrolling as soon as the direction changes, for example.